How can I connect Google Looker Studio with AWS Redshift?
I am trying to connect Looker Studio with Amazon Redshift but keep getting this error

I had to make sure everything related to connection details was the same and also tried to connect with Basic and JDBC methods but got the same error.
I read a few links as well regarding this but wasn't able to make it work, also Error message is kind of generic We encountered an error... don't even tell what could be the root cause.
https://www.googlecloudcommunity.com/gc/Looker-Studio/Redshift-connection-issue/m-p/763489/highlight/true
According to this, I tried to enable SSL and uploaded the pem file.

https://s3.amazonaws.com/redshift-downloads/amazon-trust-ca-bundle.crt

Downloaded the .crt file from the above link converted the file extension to .pem then attached it but the same issue.
If anyone from the Looker Studio community has faced this issue, please let me know.

References:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/connecting-ssl-support.html
https://support.google.com/looker-studio/answer/11377200#zippy=%2Cin-this-article


found a solution myself, here's the guide:

Download SSL certificate from here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/connecting-ssl-support.html

This is the URL:  https://s3.amazonaws.com/redshift-downloads/amazon-trust-ca-bundle.crt
It will download amazon-trust-ca-bundle.crt on your PC
rename the file to amazon-trust-ca-bundle.pem


Make sure it's publicly accessible (Amazon Redshift Serverless > Workgroup configuration > <your-wrokgroup>)




Add this rule to your Security Group (Amazon Redshift Serverless > Workgroup configuration > <your-wrokgroup> > VPC security group)



Then once all of the above step is completed try to Authenticate again


This guy is amazing his video also helped me along: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=22K0PxjwIa0
